# notepad++ search and replace columns

Tags: notepad++

I have used the systinternals tool listdlls to list all loaded dlls for a certain process.

Now I have a list that looks like this:

```
0x0000000077260000  0x1a9000  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
    Verified:   Microsoft Windows
    Publisher:  Microsoft Corporation
    Description:    DLL für NT-Layer
    Product:    Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®
    Version:    6.1.7601.18247
    File version:   6.1.7601.18247
    Create time:    Thu Aug 29 04:17:08 2013

0x00000000744c0000  0x3f000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll
    Verified:   Microsoft Windows
    Publisher:  Microsoft Corporation
    Description:    Win32 Emulation on NT64
    Product:    Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    Version:    6.1.7601.18247
    File version:   6.1.7601.18247
    Create time:    Thu Aug 29 04:19:10 2013
```

This list is pretty long. Now I would like to use notepad++ to change every "0x0000*" line into "only c:\*".

Is this possible? Thanks alot in advance
Wolfgang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the following help?

Find:  `(0x00.*).(0x.*).(C:.*)`

Replace: `\3`

[image]